# Assp.net Core exeption ('Invalid column name 'ClassRoomClassId')

Tags: entity-framework, orm, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have a problem with ASP.NET Core scaffolding. I just applied scaffolding on a simple relational model and I got this SqlException.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'ClassRoomClassId'.'
```

All I have two models

**ClassRoom**

```
public class ClassRoom
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Student**

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StuId { get; set; }
    public string StuName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
    public int? ClassId { get; set; }
    public ClassRoom ClassRoom { get; set; }
}
```

And I get the exception when executing **Students/Index**.

```
// GET: Students
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.Student.ToList());
}
```

*I have no column with this name 'ClassRoomClassId' !!*
what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `[ForeignKey("ClassId")]` to `[ForeignKey("ClassRoom")]` or placing it on `ClassRoom` property:

```
public class Student
{
    ...
    public int? ClassId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
    public ClassRoom ClassRoom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you soooooo much ..... both changes are working :)

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA was glad to help!